# /dev/random returning always the same sequence

Tags: c, linux, random

I was going to use /dev/random output as a seed for key generation for openssl, then I wrote this small program just to check what I was going to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define LEN 128

void uc2hex(char* hex, unsigned char* uc, unsigned short uc_len)
{
    FILE* bp=fmemopen(hex,2*uc_len+1,"w");
    unsigned short i;
    for(i=0;i<uc_len;i++)
    {
        fprintf(bp,"%02x",uc[i]);
        //printf("%02x\n",uc[i]);
        //fprintf(bp,"%d-",i);
    }
    fprintf(bp,"%c",'\0');
    fclose(bp);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char buf[LEN];
    char str[2*LEN+1];
    int fd=open("/dev/random",O_RDONLY);
    read(fd,buf,LEN);
    uc2hex(str,buf,LEN);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I ran the program some one or two times and everything seemed to work fine, but then I ran it four times again in short sequence and this is the output:

```
[walter@eM350 ~]$ ./random 
0ee08c942ddf901af1278ba8f335b5df8db7cf18e5de2a67ac200f320a7a20e84866f533667a7e66a4572b3bf83d458e6f71f325783f2e3f921868328051f8f296800352cabeaf00000000000000000001000000000000005d08400000000000c080300e00000000000000000000000010084000000000000006400000000000
[walter@eM350 ~]$ ./random 
1f69a0b931c16f796bbb1345b3f58f17f74e3df600000000bb03400000000000ffffffff00000000880e648aff7f0000a88103b4d67f000000305cb4d67f000030415fb4d67f0000000000000000000001000000000000005d08400000000000c080300e00000000000000000000000010084000000000000006400000000000
[walter@eM350 ~]$ ./random 
4e8a1715238644a840eb66d9ff7f00002e4e3df600000000bb03400000000000ffffffff00000000a8ec66d9ff7f0000a871a37ad97f00000020fc7ad97f00003031ff7ad97f0000000000000000000001000000000000005d08400000000000c080300e00000000000000000000000010084000000000000006400000000000
[walter@eM350 ~]$ ./random 
598c57563e8951e6f0173f0cff7f00002e4e3df600000000bb03400000000000ffffffff0000000058193f0cff7f0000a8e1cbda257f0000009024db257f000030a127db257f0000000000000000000001000000000000005d08400000000000c080300e00000000000000000000000010084000000000000006400000000000
```

Theese seem to me everything but 128-bytes random strings, since they are mostly the same. Then, excluding the possibility that the NSA tampered with the linux kernel random-number-generator, I could only guess that this has something to do with the available entropy in my machine, which gets exhausted when I ask too many bytes in sequence. My questions are:
1) Is this guess correct?
2) Assuming 1) is correct, how do I know whether there is enough entropy to generate real random bytes sequence?

Comment: Use `/dev/urandom`. Real randomness is scarce and shouldn't be wasted like that.

Comment: @KerrekSB Define "wasted". If I read from `/dev/urandom`, the entropy count is decreased as well. The difference is that `urandom`doesn't stop if the count has reached 0.

Comment: @glglgl: The difference is that `urandom` uses the true randomness to seed pseudo-randomness. It's true that you get better randomness if more is available, but the pseudo-randomness is at least as good as it can be given the available randomness.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was aware of that, but I was under the impression that using `urandom` would eat up entropy as well (and thus disturb `random`). But it seems that they use two completely distinct entropy pools.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the man page for read:

`Upon successful completion, read(), readv(), and pread() return the number of bytes actually read and placed in the buffer.  The system guarantees to read the number of bytes requested if the descriptor references a normal file that has that many bytes left before the end-of-file, but in no other case.`

Bottom line: check the return value from `read` and see how many bytes you actually read - there may not have been enough entropy to generate the number of bytes you requested.

```
int len = read(fd, buf, LEN);
printf("read() returned %d bytes: ", len);
if (len > 0)
{
    uc2hex(str, buf, len);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Test:

```
$ ./a.out 
read() returned 16 bytes: c3d5f6a8ee11ddc16f00a0dea4ef237a
$ ./a.out
read() returned 8 bytes: 24e23c57852a36bb
$ ./a.out 
read() returned 16 bytes: 4ead04d1eedb54ee99ab1b25a41e735b
$
```

Comment: Of course... I was thrown off by the fact that the OP didn't witness outright *blocking* of the call. I guess a small amount of natural randomness occured in between calls. Good call, and definitely +1.

Answer (score 2):

As other people have suggested, you need to check the return value for the number of bytes read.

If /dev/random did not have sufficent bytes available, it will have returned fewer.

However, you still use the *expected* length in your following calls:

```
uc2hex(str,buf,LEN);
printf("%s\n",str);
```

So, you are converting and printing uninitialised memory. I am not surprised that subsequent calls then show the same value - since if that memory hasn't been written to between calls, the value wont change.

EDIT: Better would be:

```
int nBytes=read(fd,buf,LEN);
uc2hex(str,buf,nBytes);
printf("%s\n",str);
```